# Can't use ó in the target of a link?

Tags: bug, status-deferred

I was trying to make a link to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamón but it clearly doesn't work. Even trying this or this doesn't work (view source, 'this' should be a link).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the ó character (as %C3%B3). [Some forum-friendly browsers](http://getfirefox.com/) will do this for you when you copy the url out of the address bar... [This should be a valid link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam%C3%B3n).

Comment: Safari is lame I guess. Thanks Knives.

Answer (score -1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamon also works -- note that Wikipedia frequently supports the plain-ASCII version of international characters.

Comment: Yes, but it takes you to a disambiguation page instead of directly to the one regarding ham.