# bug in inline links in comments.

Tags: bug, status-deferred

recently I tried to add a link to this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_(coffee_pot) using an inline link [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_%28coffee_pot%29) in a comment as you can see (by clicking on the like this back there <--) it thinks the bracket is the end of the link and so creates an invalid link.

Can anything be done about this or is it just too much like hard work to fix?

EDIT:

I see that the actual full link doesn't work either, which makes me think that something light be able to be done after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [use this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moka_%28coffee_pot%29). URL-encode the open and closing parenthesis to `%28` and `%29` respectively.

See also: [Can't use ó in the target of a link?](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347/cant-use-o-in-the-target-of-a-link)

Comment: thanks.........

Comment: Yea, convenient, it's not. Jeff applying a status-defered to my question seems to imply that maybe this will all get fixed one day.