# bug With certain typos Neat Link showing in Review but not in actual post

Tags: bug, links

This is a very trivial bug and probably will not be fixed. But maybe it should be documented, possibly just by a post such as this.

- See also related [bug in inline links in comments.](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/bug-in-inline-links-in-comments)

How to reproduce.

Make or attempt to make a naked html link such as the one above but with a typo, for instance omit a space between the link and the text.https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/bug-in-inline-links-in-comments In this case note that the text immediately  is terminated with a full stop|period.

Result in review this link can be seen and used. (Clarification: go in to edit mode and you will see what I mean. In edit mode the useable hyperlink is seen.) As expected. BUT **Unexpected** when the question is posted there is no clickable link only the text.

**Problem**  I expect consistency. If something works in Preview I feel it should work when posted.
**Corrective Action** I would suggest either:

- It be fixed so that text works in the final post.
- Or probably a better course of action would be to have the preview behave in the same way as the final post and break the link display in preview.

Comment: Two notes: Firstly, I had to go into edit mode to see what you meant about the second link not working. You could perhaps clarify this. Secondly, this meta site is probably not the right place for bug reports about the functioning of the site, although I'm not immediately sure where you should go instead.

Comment: Noted. But I am expecting the bug is so trivial it would be unlikely to be fixed unless it so happened that the relevant code was being reviewed and changed for another reason. I have edited OP to try to clarify issue is seen comparing post with edit mode review.